# Split array in puppet manifest on one line

Tags: arrays, split, puppet, hiera

Is it possible to do this on one line?

```
$fruit = hiera('fruit_hiera')
$fruit_split = split($fruit, ',')
```

The relevant line from the YAML data source is:

```
fruit_hiera : 'apple,banana,orange'
```

Comment: Like this? `$fruit_split = split(hiera('fruit_hiera'), ',')`

Comment: Depends on your version of hiera and puppet.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, would you care to elaborate?  As far as I am aware, the most obvious way to do it works with any combination of Puppet and Hiera that work together at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would have to go digging through my PE tickets to find  where hiera inlining became something that works. I think it was around 3.8.0.

Comment: @Stefan worked . thank you.

Comment: @Stefan you should probably convert that comment into an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have a code pattern like this:

```
temp = value
method(temp)
```

You can *inline* the temporary variable by replacing `temp` with `value`:

```
method(value)
```

Applied to your example:

```
$fruit = hiera('fruit_hiera')
$fruit_split = split($fruit, ',')
```

becomes:

```
$fruit_split = split(hiera('fruit_hiera'), ',')
```